# Count Duplicate Values in multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Below is a sample of my array. I am trying to count every time a user_id is in the array. I am trying to count each time a user_id is in the array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 57002892
        [page_id] => 109446562415595
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 515576073
        [page_id] => 109446562415595
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 560299932
        [page_id] => 109446562415595
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 607960053
        [page_id] => 109446562415595
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 607960053
        [page_id] => 109446562415595
    )
)
```

and this should output the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 57002892
        [count] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 515576073
        [count] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 560299932
        [count] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 607960053
        [count] => 2
    )
)
```

is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Let your example input be $input_array in the code below:

```
$user_id_hash = array();
foreach( $input_array as $occur )
{
    if( !array_key_exists( $occur['user_id'], $user_id_hash ) )
    {
        $user_id_hash[$occur['user_id']] = 0;
    }
    $user_id_hash[$occur['user_id']]++;
}
$user_id_arr = array();
foreach( $user_id_hash as $user_id => $count )
{
    $user_id_arr[] = array( 'user_id' => $user_id, 'count' => $count );
}
```

If you're ok with the associative array, you can drop the second loop.

Comment: what is '$user_id' ? That gives me error: Notice: Undefined variable: user_id

Comment: Should have been "$user_id_hash" in lines 4, 6 and 8. I updated the answer to reflect.